# Change project interpreter after creation Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've already changed the default project interpreter in PyCharm under `File` | `Default Settings` | `Project Interpreter` to Python 3.6, but when I try to write variable annotations (e.g. `int: x = 6`) PyCharm complains that `Python version 3.4 does not support variable annotations`, as Python 3.4 was the former interpreter I was using.

How do I change the syntax check to that of Python 3.6? Or any other interpreter, for that matter.

Comment: While you set the default (which applies to new projects), you still need to set the project interpreter on existing projects. Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default interpreter (and the default settings in general) apply on newly created projects, if you want to change an already created project settings you need to:

1. *File* > *Settings* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as shortcut)> *Project:*  > *Project interpreter*
2. In the project interpreter dropdown list you can specify your interpreter by selecting the appropriate from the list
3. In here you can even create a new virtual environment for your project by clicking on <kbd>⚙</kbd> > *Create VirtualEnv*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I recently downloaded 2017.1 and that is working with the new syntax perfectly. Nevertheless, I tried this on the old before installing and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know mate :)